# Updating to Mac OS 10.9 broke my Apache Virtual Hosts

Tags: php, macos, apache

When I updated to my OS 10.9, my apache virtual host setup broke. I first discovered that the include line for the extra/httpd-vhost.conf file had been commented out, like so:

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

So I uncommented. Now, the virutal hosts seemed to be operating, but the php code is just being pulled up as a text file. It's not running the code. Seems as though, perhaps, the php link is no longer working?  Does that make sense? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was simply that the LoadModule line for php5 in httpd.conf had also been commented out:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

I uncommented and everything seems to be working now.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look in the **/private/etc/apache2/extra** directory. Mac OS X renames your old config files and adds fresh vanilla ones. I had the same problem when I upgraded to Mavericks.

Comment: this wasn't the solution i needed, but this is good advice i think!